# The SIM card inserted in this iPhone does not appear to be supported

Tags: iphone, sim

I received following message after I restored my iPhone OS to 4.2: `The SIM card inserted in this iPhone does not appear to be supported`. How can I use my SIM?

Comment: Did it work with this SIM card before you restored the phone? Does the SIM card work in another phone? Is the iPhone netlocked to a different provider maybe?

Comment: My brother was using iPhone with other Sim before, when he gave me, it had problem "Restore Required", so I restored to latest OS i.e 4.2 with my Sim & I got above problem.  Problem’s Full Descriptions “Only Compatiable Sim Cards from a supported Carrier may be used to activate the iPhone. Please insert the Sim Card that came with ur iPhone or visit a supported carrier’s Store to receive a replacement Sim Card”. Can I activate my iPhone with my Standard SIM ??

Comment: One reason the message may appear is a netlocked iPhone with a SIM card from another provider. Does this apply in your case? Also: Do you have access to your brother's SIM card and can you try it with this one?

Comment: What is a "Standard SIM"?

Comment: Sudip, if you hope to have answers that are more helpful to your situation. At least provide the following: (1) iPhone model, (2) Carrier/Telco that your iPhone worked OK on, and (3) the Carrier/Telco that doesn't work. We can't minds (at least I can't).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your carrier, some SIM batches are known to be problematic (Bell is a good example). Outside of that, the most obvious is if the iPhone was jailbroken and unlocked, the restore would remove the modification and return it to proper function. If everything should be working legitimately, you can take it to an Apple Store and they can look up which carrier the unit is locked to (if any).

Answer (score 1):

Reboot!
I had that problem once. I rebooted the phone and it worked again. You also might need to connect to iTunes.

Comment: I can’t solve my problem with restarting iPhone bcoz my power switch don’t work properly. Is there any alternate way to Switch On/Off iPhone ??

Comment: You can run the battery right down until the iphone turns off. When you charge it up again it will boot up again.